# Сочетание причастия и деепричастия

Tags: деепричастия

Не могу объяснить причину, по которой мне режет слух сочетание «…наблюдавшего за ней, припав…», кажется, что возможна лишь формулировка «…который наблюдал за ней, припав…».

Возможно ли первое сочетание? Не нарушает ли оно правил? И если нарушает, то какие?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выглянув из папоротников, Щербатая увидела молодого огненно-рыжего кота, **наблюдавшего за ней, припав** к земле, словно она была дичью!

Предложение грамматически некорректно. По определению, деепричастие **обозначает добавочное действие, которое поясняет основное действие, выраженное глаголом-сказуемым.** Из этого следует, что деепричастие не может относиться к причастию.

Возможен такой вариант: Выглянув из папоротников, Щербатая увидела молодого огненно-рыжего кота, **лежа наблюдавшего за ней**, словно она была дичью!

В этом случае **деепричастие переходит в наречие и теряет значение действия**, а наречие может пояснять признаковые формы (причастия и прилагательные).

Comment: Предлагаю вариант, сохраняющий красоту изложения: Выглянув из папоротников, Щербатая увидела молодого огненно-рыжего кота, припавшего к земле и наблюдавшего за ней, словно она была дичью!

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с Вами. О том, как плохо нагромождение причастий и деепричастий, говорит Нора Галь в начале своей книги "Слово живое и мёртвое". Она говорит также о том, что часто время деепричастия, которое должно предшествовать времени основной части предложения, у авторов на деле явно ***следует за*** тем, о чём говорится в основной части. То есть очевидно, что они пытаются выразить такой порядок, но получается у них неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

> **Сочетание причастия и деепричастия**
>
> Не могу объяснить причину, по которой мне режет слух сочетание
>   *«…**наблюдавшего** за ней, **припав**…»...*

В самом отнесении деепричастного оборота к причастию, думаю,  ошибки нет.

К примеру, вряд ли очень сильно резало бы Ваш слух такое предложение:

*Выглянув из папоротников, она увидела молодого огненно-рыжего кота, **наблюдавшего,  припав** к земле, за двумя маленькими птенчиками.*

То, что само предложение, частично процитированное Вами, составлено некорректно, спору нет. Но вряд ли эту некорректность можно объяснять тем, что "деепричастие не может относиться к причастию".

[**Решил открыть новую тему...**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428411/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8)