# Деепричастие при причастии

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

В одном из недавних ответов на форуме прозвучало следующее:

> [Сочетание причастия и деепричастия](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428302/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F)
>
> По определению, деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие, которое
>   поясняет основное действие, выраженное глаголом-сказуемым. Из этого
>   следует, что **деепричастие не может относиться к причастию**.

Удивило то, что ответ с такой аргументацией получил  и продолжает получать активную поддержку со стороны участников нашего форума.

***"Деепричастие не может относиться к причастию"***. Но так ли это на самом деле?

[**Розенталь**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091288.html) считал, что может:

> В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не
>   выражающего действие подлежащего:
>
> 1) **если производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием,
>   совпадает с производителем действия, обозначенного другой глагольной
>   формой** (инфинитивом, **причастием**, деепричастием), например:
>   *Автору было предложено внести в рукопись дополнения, учитывая последние достижения науки в данной области; Ничем нельзя было
>   удержать напора **волн, нахлынувших** на берег, **сметая** всё на
>   своём пути.*

Розенталь был не прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Розенталь прав был в главном и предусмотрительно упомянул об ограничении "в ряде случаев", но приведённый им пример неудачен и находится за пределами естественного ограничения. Он режет слух и напоминает о той "шляпе" потому, что соединяет в себе причастие+деепричастие совершенного+несовершенного видов. Здесь это разрывает во времени действие, выраженное деепричастием, с глаголом, от которого образовано причастие: нахлынули, а после этого стали непрерывно "сметать". Если бы расхождения причастия с деепричастием по виду не было, сохранилась бы более тесная связь между двумя действиями (здесь: одновременность), и выражение стало бы допустимым: **... хлещущих на берег, сметая всё на своём пути.** Из всего разнообразия деепричастных оборотов больше шансов к сочетаемости с причастием у таких, которые по смыслу близки к обстоятельству образа действия, например:

> Его сбил пьяный водитель, разъезжавший по улицам, не удосуживаясь
>   посматривать на светофоры.
>
> Он увидел Петьку, бегущего из кабинета директора сломя голову и не
>   реагируя на крики одноклассников.

Comment: Его сбил пьяный водитель, разъезжавший, не глядя по сторонам. Он увидел Петьку, бегущего, не реагируя на крики одноклассников. Здесь нужно обособлять обороты? Кажется, что они  совершенно утратили значение действия и выступают в функции наречий. Так, может быть, более распространенные и обособленные обороты также выступают в роли "обособленных наречных выражений на основе деепричастий" и поэтому в меньшей степени "режут слух"?

Comment: Так тут и есть образ действия: *нахлынувших на берег (как?) сметая всё на своём пути* (мне вообще слух не режет). Распространённость оборота способствует его обособлению. А вот "сломя голову и не реагируя" как-то не звучит, потому что "не реагируя" грамматически к образу действия не относится. Во фразе "Петька бежал, не реагируя на крики одноклассников" прямо просится запятая.

Answer (score 2):

1) Ничем нельзя было удержать напора волн, **нахлынувших на берег, сметая всё на своём пути.**

Розенталь, конечно, авторитет, но мне это предложение не нравится.  В этой теме он, кажется, пишет о параллельных конструкциях, вот и рассмотрим параллельную конструкцию: Ничем нельзя было удержать напора волн, **нахлынувших на берег и сметающих всё на своём пути.** Чем это предложение хуже, **какая семантика в нем не выражена**, так что надо было соединять деепричастие с причастием, строя весьма сомнительную форму.

**2) Поэтому народ против (цитаты из Интернета)**

а) ― Вот в этой фразе вас что-нибудь задевает? ― Конечно. Неправильно употреблен деепричастный оборот. Почти по Чехову: "Проезжая мимо станции, с меня слетела шляпа. ― Хотя у меня такое же мнение, НО это взято из Розенталя. ― Интересная ссылка. Но Розенталь для меня "не истина в последней инстанции". Я правлю все, что "режет слух".

б) Я бы отказалась от употребления таких конструкций, т.к. у наших школьников (и студентов) и так в грамматике разброд и шатание, а это может вызвать ещё большую путаницу. Как результат - будут слетать шляпы, подъезжая к вокзалу!

3) **И последний вопрос**: а есть ли еще примеры, кто из наших классиков или современных известных писателей пользовался подобными конструкциями? Тогда можно подумать, поразмышлять над их целесообразностью и тогда уж решать, прав ли был Розенталь.