# Может ли деепричастный оборот относиться к причастию?

Tags: грамматика

1) Только что разбирали грамматику предложения : Я пою офицерам, матерей **пожалевшим, возвратив** им обратно живых сыновей. Было сказано, что грамматических ошибок нет.

2) Но обычно **деепричастный оборот относится к глаголу**, правила употребления деепричастий довольно строгие. [Правила употребления деепричастных оборотов | genon.ru](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=d65ada4d-db68-47cf-b485-6ab65eb72b74)

Вот один из примеров, когда деепричастный оборот относится к дополнению  и грамматически зависит **от инфинитива:** Дом его был полон гостями, готовыми **тешить** его барскую праздность, **разделяя** шумные, а иногда и буйные его увеселения (А.С. Пушкин).

3) **Но в приведенном примере деепричастный оборот относится к причастию.** У наших классиков информации на эту тему мне не удалось найти.

Для сравнения (деепричастный оборот относится к глаголу): Я пою офицерам, которые **пожалели** матерей, **возвратив** им обратно живых сыновей.

Comment: Здесь обсуждалось мнение Розенталя о том, что такая связь возможна: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428411/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/428412

Comment: Спасибо, нашла у Розенталя в "Параллельных конструкциях". Знаменитые волны: Ничем нельзя было удержать напора волн, нахлынувших на берег, сметая все на своем пути.  Но здесь деепричастие несовершенного вида, обозначает одновременность двух действий и близко по семантике к наречию (а наречия могут относиться к прилагательным и причастиям). А вот "возвратившись" - деепричастие сов. вида, обозначает сдвинутое действие (до или после).

Comment: В стихотворении речь идет фактически об однородных действиях без указания на сдвиг во времени (пожалевших и возвративших, если бы не рамки стихотворной формы). Отсюда и претензии к грамматической форме деепричастия "возвратив".

Answer (score 2):

Строго говоря, деепричастный оборот указывает на действие, относящееся к подлежащему данного предложения. Встречающиеся у писателей-классиков отступления от этой нормы представляют собой либо галлицизмы, либо результат влияния народного языка...

*Имея право выбирать оружие, жизнь его была в моих руках* (Пушкин).
*Проезжая на возвратном пути в первый раз весною знакомую березовую рощу, у меня голова закружилась и забилось сердце от смутного сладкого ожидания* (Тургенев).

Розенталь допускает присоединение дееприч. оборота к любой глагольной форме — инфинитиву, причастию, деепричастию:

б) если относится к причастию или деепричастию, обозначающему действие, субъект которого не совпадает с субъектом действия, выраженного сказуемым. Она не ответила ему, задумчиво следя за игрой волн, взбегавших на берег, колыхая тяжелый баркас (Горький)

[**Параллельные синтаксические конструкции**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091288.html)

Ещё примеры из худ. литературы:

*Его сбил пьяный водитель, разъезжавший по улицам, не удосуживаясь посматривать на светофоры.

Он увидел Петьку, бегущего из кабинета директора сломя голову, не реагируя на крики одноклассников.*

Однако я не могу не согласиться с Ю. Поляковым, обвинившим Газманова в "неряшливости" грамматики. Рифма и ритм у него главенствуют над качеством речи, как и у многих авторов хитов. К поэтам у нас высокие требования, хотелось бы видеть их безукоризненную грамотность.

Comment: Людмила, так ведь у Газманова совпадают субъект действия двух глагольных форм. У него так и написано:   если производитель действия, ***обозначенного деепричастием, совпадает с производителем действия***, обозначенного другой глагольной формой (инфинитивом, причастием, деепричастием),

Comment: А вы пишете, что не совпадает.

Comment: А где Вы нашли у меня что-то именно об этом предложении? Напротив, я говорю, что здесь нет ошибки, это возможно,но "неряшливость" всё-таки присутствует, или "вольность", как хотите.

Comment: Людмила, вы пишете, что "не совпадает", а у Розенталя написано, что "совпает совпадает с производителем действия".

Answer (score 0):

По строгим правилам деепричастие должно относится к глаголу или именному сказуемому. Как заметил @Morkovkin, формально фраза означает, что автор поет, возвратив сыновей. Конечно, Газманов имел ввиду не это, и все сразу понимают этот текст именно так, как хотел автор. А раз все понятно — так может простим автору эту поэтическую вольность?
Вот, например, статья, в которой говорится: **Поэтический текст является для авторов полем для экспериментов с деепричастными оборотами**.

[**1.4. Деепричастие в диалектах и просторечии и их отражение в литературном языке**](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#14)

**Дополнение о строгих правилах**
Вот что пишет Е. И. Литневская, на которую ссылается Грамота.ру:
"Деепричастие должно указывать на действие того предмета (лица), который назван **подлежащим**, причем этот предмет (лицо) должен быть субъектом двух действий — названного в **сказуемом** и в деепричастии. Если эти требования не соблюдаются, получаются неправильные предложения..."
Все остальное — предмет дискуссии.

Comment: ,деепричастие,как правило, относится к глаголу, но может относится и к  причастию. Песня - в пример.