# Правильно ли употреблён деепричастный оборот?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Сомневаюсь насчёт правильности употребления деепричастного поворота в данном предложении: "Зная этого мальчишку, Саше было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью, что именно он сейчас дрожит и плачет прямо перед ним". Проясните этот момент, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428411/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8

Answer (score 1):

1) Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), **относится, как правило, к подлежащему** данного предложения.

2) В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, **не выражающего действия подлежащего:**

**— в безличном предложении при инфинитиве,** например: *Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.* 
[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)

3) ***Зная этого мальчишку***, Саше было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью, что именно он сейчас дрожит и плачет прямо перед ним.

В этом безличном предложении **есть инфинитив** (трудно смириться, зная...), но стилистика кажется **некорректной.**

4) Возможные **варианты редактирования:**

(1) *Зная этого мальчишку,  было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью...*

(2) *Зная всё об этом мальчишке, Саше было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью...*

5) **Вывод (как предположение)**

Возможно, в приведенном предложении **нужно исключить значение деепричастного оборота как обстоятельства образа действия.** Деепричастный оборот должен иметь значение условия или причины (если знать, так как знал).

Answer (score 1):

> *"Зная этого мальчишку, Саше было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью,
>   что именно он сейчас дрожит и плачет прямо перед ним"*
>   Правильно ли употреблён деепричастный оборот?

Если вопрос чисто практический, то есть стоит ли эту конструкцию использовать в реальном тексте, то лучше не надо (см. Sharon).
Но вот если нужно подвести теорию, то это очень спорный момент. Вряд ли мы тут придем к единому мнению.

В школьной, а до недавнего времени - и в академической, практике подобные конструкции характеризовали как "деепричастный оборот в пассивном/безличном предложении" - и полностью отвергались. 
Но сейчас все чаще применяется иной критерий - действие: действие деепричастия и основного глагола (или той части речи от которой деепричастие зависит) должно относиться к одному лицу.

> В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не
>   выражающего действия подлежащего: 1) если производитель действия,
>   обозначенного деепричастием, совпадает с производителем действия,
>   обозначенного другой глагольной формой (инфинитивом, причастием,
>   деепричастием), например: Автору было предложено внести в рукопись
>   дополнения, учитывая изменения, происшедшие в жизни общества за
>   последнее время; Ничем нельзя было удержать напора волн, нахлынувших
>   на берег, сметая все на своем пути; 2) в безличном предложении при
>   инфинитиве, например: Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея
>   в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха. Если же в
>   безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться
>   деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически
>   неоправданно, например. «Уезжая из родного города, мне стало грустно»;
>   «Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что она нуждается в
>   серьезной доработке». Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного
>   оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия,
>   выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного
>   деепричастием, не совпадают, например: «Получив признание широких
>   читательских масс, книга была переиздана».
>   *Розенталь
>   Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию 
>   § 212. Деепричастные обороты*

То есть даже Розенталь, хотя и с оговоркой, допускает конструкции, подобные рассматриваемой.

Скажу больше, можно ожидать, что со временем и ряд отвергаемых Розенталем конструкций постепенно перейдут в разряд допустимых - это прежде всего "пассивные" предложения с глаголом "быть" (во всех лично-временных формах) с инфинитивом. Лишь бы критерий производителя действия не нарушался.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, в предложении попросту неудачен **порядок слов**, в результате его стилистические особенности создают *ощущение речевой ошибки*. Вероятная причина этого в том, что производитель обоих действий (деепричастия и глагола) помещён между деепричастным оборотом и инфинитивом, выражающим основное действие. Разрыв этих двух действий затрудняет отнесение обоих их к "Саше": после прочтения ДО ожидается производитель основного действия в именительном падеже, но его появления не происходит. Исправить ситуацию можно, напрямую связав оба действия между собой (изменением *порядка слов*: **зная, смириться**), тогда их сочетание при чтении легко отнести к Саше (как можно было бы отнести и к любому гипотетическому производителю действия, независимо от его упоминания, - "Саши" здесь могло не быть):

> Особенно трудно было Саше, *зная этого мальчишку, смириться с мыслью*,
>   что именно он сейчас дрожит и плачет прямо перед ним.