# Саше было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью... — каким членом предложения является "Саше"?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

Из [другого вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82):

> Зная этого мальчишку, **Саше** было особенно трудно смириться с мыслью, что именно он сейчас дрожит и плачет прямо перед ним

Каким членом предложения является "Саше"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это односоставное безличное предложение. Стало быть, "Саше" – это дополнение.

Но опять же: здесь речевая ошибка. На мой взгляд, лучше перефразировать, например, хотя бы так: "Зная этого мальчишку, Саша всё никак не мог смириться с мыслью, что именно он сейчас дрожит и плачет прямо перед ним".